# Css translate y making background-image disappear

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with an element when I use the translate-y in active state, it makes the background-image disappear. Click the element and you will see the image disappear.

The Css:

```
.glyphsblock i {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center, center;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 1px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease 0.1s;
}
.glyphsblock i:before {
  background: radial-gradient(#8ed3c8, #224945);
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.glyphsblock i:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
.glyph-A {
  background-image: url(https://atlasdatabase.github.io/glyphs/a.png);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="glyphsblock">
    <i class="glyph-A"></i>
</div>
```

Also a jsfiddle of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/go0tbb53/

Comment: you can replace transform: translateY(2px); ---> margin top:2px;?

https://jsfiddle.net/go0tbb53/5/

if that you need than i make an answer

Comment: Actually I want to use translate because it's more smooth than margin, using margin doesn't give a smooth "click" effet. Any idea why using translate make it disappear?

Comment: i don't understand why - but it doesn't work( you can try do not use background, and create one more <i> and set bg for him - and use z-index

Comment: It can't be margin-top because it will move all the other <i> elements that are in the same div, even in another div it moves them: https://jsfiddle.net/go0tbb53/8/
Also I need that background image because is what idetifies that block when the user click it.

Comment: are you still here? https://jsfiddle.net/go0tbb53/10/ if this is what you want - i write a question

Comment: Yep! Let me try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your CSS to remove the negative `z-index`, which can produce unpredictable results. This is what was causing the `transform` to glitch and hide the glyph icon.

I've adjusted your snippet so now the `i` itself has the radial gradient, and the `::before` pseudo-element is laying the glyph graphic on top of it.

You can see it working below:

```css
.glyphsblock i {
  background: radial-gradient(#8ed3c8, #224945);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 1px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease 0.1s;
}

.glyphsblock i::before {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center, center;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.glyphsblock i:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.glyph-A::before {
  background-image: url(https://atlasdatabase.github.io/glyphs/a.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="glyphsblock">
  <i class="glyph-A"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, It's the same approach Dmitriy did! Learned it now! Thanks

Comment: Yeah, Choosing yours then ;)  Anyway, good to see many people helping here as always! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be totally conventional, but I changed your jsfiddle to use a sized div for the background and an image for the icon itself. If you want to use multiple icons, simply make a larger wrapper div for multiple of what is currently called glyphsblock.

Also, my solution doesn't have any javascript, which is helpful :)

```css
.bg-grad {
  background: radial-gradient(#8ed3c8, #224945);
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}

.glyphsblock:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="glyphsblock">
  <div class="bg-grad">
  </div>
  <img src="https://atlasdatabase.github.io/glyphs/a.png" height=38px width=38px/>
</div>
```

Comment: None of the solutions had JavaScript?

Comment: The javascript I use for the clicked part, where it adds a new class to make the element shine.